# Pivot two DateTime rows into a pair of columns when one part of the pair may be missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016, partition-by

I am working on a time clock application for my company that is capturing clock-in/clock-out data in a table named TCPunch (TimeClock Punch). ActionID 1 = ClockIn, ActionID 2= ClockOut. If either row for a ClockIn/ClockOut pair is missing, I would like it to be null. The payroll operator will correct all missing time punches and then re-run the report.

Below is data from the TCPunch table with an ORDER BY EmployeeID, ActionTime:

| ID | EmployeeID | ActionID | ActionTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41 | 17 | 1 | 2023-04-13 07:16:26.250 |
| 11 | 69 | 1 | 2023-04-11 14:47:36.523 |
| 14 | 69 | 2 | 2023-04-11 16:47:57.220 |
| 16 | 69 | 1 | 2023-04-11 16:48:06.683 |
| 18 | 69 | 2 | 2023-04-11 17:00:00.300 |
| 36 | 119 | 2 | 2023-04-12 10:30:18.430 |

How can I write an efficient SQL statement to present the data ordered by EmployeeID, ActionTime and pivot the ActionID and ActionTime, and calculate the time diff in hours to get output like below? I have studied CTE and Partition Over for this I am having no luck and this is above my current SQL knowledge. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

| EmployeeID | ClockIn | ClockOut | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2023-04-13 07:16:26.250 | NULL | NULL |
| 69 | 2023-04-11 14:47:36.523 | 2023-04-11 16:47:57.220 | 2.005833 |
| 69 | 2023-04-11 16:48:06.683 | 2023-04-11 17:00:00.300 | 0.198333 |
| 119 | NULL | 2023-04-12 10:30:18.430 | NULL |

I figured out I can calculate hours as decimal using **DateDiff(second, ClockIn, ClockOut) / 3600.0** once I can get the data in the right format.

Comment: group a clock-out with an immediate previous clock-in, the rest stay on their own, then aggregate per group: `select EmployeeID, min(case when ActionID=1 then ActionTime end) as ClockIn, max(case when ActionID=2 then ActionTime end) as ClockOut
from (select *, sum(add1) over(partition by EmployeeID order by ActionTime rows unbounded preceding) as grp
from (select *, case when ActionID=2 and lag(ActionID) over(partition by EmployeeID order by ActionTime) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as add1
from TCPunch) as t) as g
group by EmployeeID, grp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group every clock in and out that belong together by employee and then use [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
select   EmployeeID
        ,[1]                             as ClockIn
        ,[2]                             as ClockOut
        ,datediff(second,[1],[2])/3600.0 as hours
from 
(
select   EmployeeID 
        ,ActionID   
        ,ActionTime
        ,count(case ActionID when 1 then 1 end) over(partition by EmployeeID order by ID) as flg
from     t
) t
pivot    (max(ActionTime) for ActionID in([1], [2])) t
order by EmployeeID
```

| EmployeeID | ClockIn | ClockOut | hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 2023-04-13 07:16:26.000 | null | null |
| 69 | 2023-04-11 14:47:36.000 | 2023-04-11 16:47:57.000 | 2.005833 |
| 69 | 2023-04-11 16:48:06.000 | 2023-04-11 17:00:00.000 | 0.198333 |
| 119 | null | 2023-04-12 10:30:18.000 | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oWks_ugS)

Comment: This is working pretty well. The only issue I see is if the user is manually editing the data and creates a ClockIn action that has an ID value > than the corresponding ClockOut ID (Action 1 below Action 2 in ID order). It's easy to visually see the issue in the data and they can fix by deleting the pair, and re-entering in the correct ClockIn, ClockOut order.

Comment: @DavidChristian .. there is a chance that some Action2 rows might “disappear” eg: for an employee there are consecutive rows Action1, Action2, Action2, Action2. All 3 action2 rows have the same count(previous Action1) and they are aggregated, out of the 3 only 1 will appear as max(ActionTime) the other two are lost.

Answer (score 1):

[Answered by @lptr in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010785/pivot-two-datetime-rows-into-a-pair-of-columns-when-one-part-of-the-pair-may-be#comment134060074_76010785)

---

Group a clock-out with an immediate previous clock-in, the rest stay on their own, then aggregate per group:

```
select
  EmployeeID,
  min(case when ActionID = 1 then ActionTime end) as ClockIn,
  max(case when ActionID = 2 then ActionTime end) as ClockOut
from (
    select *,
      sum(add1) over (partition by EmployeeID
                order by ActionTime rows unbounded preceding) as grp
    from (
        select *,
          case when ActionID = 2
            and lag(ActionID) over (partition by EmployeeID order by ActionTime) = 1
            then 0
            else 1 end as add1
        from TCPunch
    ) as t
) as g
group by
  EmployeeID,
  grp;
```